# Returning to same scroll position via back button on Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, scroll, android-recyclerview

Click on `RecyclerView` takes me to a different activity. I have created `onPause` and `onResume` methods which allow me to return back to the same scroll position when I press back key on the Phone. I have also enabled `setdisplayhomeasupenabled` on the action bar but when I press the back button on the Action bar it takes me back to the `RecyclerView` but not at the same scroll position.
What can be done to ensure that the back button in the action bar acts same as the back button on the phone and takes me to that saved scroll position?

Comment: Are you saving your view state ? LayoutManager does that automatically for you, if you have provided an id to your RecyclerView.

Comment: yep i m saving the state....can u tell me which method is used when i press back button on action bar which was created using actionbar.setdisplayhomeasupenabled

Comment: Are you using toolbar ?

Comment: Please, post some code, so I cal help you

Comment: I am using toolbar. The toolbar of the page which opens on listItemClicked has  setdisplayhomeasupenabled  and when i click the back button on the page it takes me back to the recyclerview page but with top position as position 0

Comment: So you are not saving your view state, otherwise the Recycler would be exactly as you left it of.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform the click, you can save the position in a global variable in the first activity and the clicked instance in a View object, then when you come back, in the on resume method you can check if the variable is setup, then you scroll to that item like this:
myRecyclerView.scrollTo(POSITION_IN_RECYCLERVIEW, VIEW_IN_POSITION.getTop());

Hope it helps!